# In a cyclic pentagon $ABCDE$, prove $\frac{a}{\sin(B+E)}=\frac{d}{\sin(C+E)}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

I've found this question online without a solution, I have tried myself and I couldn't go further than what I've mentioned in the picture.

**Question:**[image]

**My attempt** [image]

So I simplified the question into proving $\frac{a}{\sin \beta} = \frac{d}{\sin \alpha}$. It seems to me that the sine law will be used in some way, but I don't know how.

Comment: It now follows immediately from the sine rule for a triangle that $\frac{a}{\sin\beta}=2R$, $R$ the radius of the circle.  Similarly $\frac{d}{\sin\alpha}$.

Comment: I thought about that but I felt it wouldn't be the radius of the same circle. Thank you!

Comment: It will be in the same circle because a circle is determined by three points its passing through (as well as other criteria).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\hat{CD}=2\alpha,$ $\hat{DE}=2\beta,$ $\hat{AE}=2\gamma,$ $\hat{AB}=2\delta$, $\hat {BC}=2\epsilon$ and $R$ be a radius of the circumcircle.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\frac{2R\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\alpha+\epsilon+\delta)}=\frac{2R\sin\delta}{\sin(\beta+\gamma+\delta+\alpha+\epsilon+\delta)}$$ or $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+540^{\circ})}=\frac{\sin\delta}{\sin(\delta+540^{\circ})}$$ or
$$-1=-1$$ and we are done!